# Using JAVA to extract Microsoft Word Form Field Data

Tags: java, ms-word

I am using Doc4j and try to extract msword form data.
It can be easily do with VBA http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/extract_batch_form_data.html

I am using FieldRef to extract the MSWord docx form field data.
I can get the field name, and just the first line of data in the text fields, but it cannot extract the form field data with more than one line.
I cannot find similar solution from POI too.

Here is the sample data
http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/form-field-extraction-t2078.html?sid=7b4cd3ba2ba947ebbe186ad7df88b2fc

Thanks,
Cyrus Wong

Comment: try using Apache POI

Comment: I was tried to search the related information on POI, but I cannot get the hints to extract msword form data as well. That's is why I use Docx4j instead.